# getting text field value from view page into controllers page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a text field "tf_Designation" in a view page, see below:

```
<% form_for(:search) do |f| %>
    <table> 
          <tr>
             <td align="center">
                <%= f.text_field :tf_Designation,placeholder: "Designation" %>
             </td>
          </tr>
    </table>
<% end %>
```

I want to get text field value into a controllers page and I am doing like below:

```
def search
    @blah=params[:search][:tf_Designation]
    if !params[:search][:tf_Designation].blank?
       @Designation = params[:search][:tf_Designation]
       render '/index'
    end
  end
```

`And I do not have search model.` But it gave me error at this line `@blah=params[:search][:tf_Designation]`. The error is below:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

Kindly suggest me where I make mistake, waiting for your reply. Thanks

Comment: If you don't submit the form, how can you get the value to the specific controller?

Comment: is this even valid ruby/rails? `<%= f.text_field :tf_Designation,placeholder: "Designation" %>`?  Looks more like it should be `<%= f.text_field :tf_Designation, :placeholder => "Designation" %>`

Comment: If it show me my view page then I click on submit buttom. It show me error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's most likely an issue with how Rails processes [`form_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) - we've only ever used instance variables with it (which can be populated by a resource):

**form_for**

> Form helpers are designed to make working with resources much easier
>   compared to using vanilla HTML.
>
> Typically, a form designed to create or update a resource reflects the
>   identity of the resource in several ways
>
> (i) the url that the form is
>   sent to (the form element's action attribute) should result in a
>   request being routed to the appropriate controller action (with the
>   appropriate :id parameter in the case of an existing resource)
>
> (ii)
>   input fields should be named in such a way that in the controller
>   their values appear in the appropriate places within the params hash,
>
> (iii) **for an existing record, when the form is initially
>   displayed, input fields corresponding to attributes of the resource
>   should show the current values** of those attributes.

---

[**form_tag**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag)

I would highly recommend switching to `form_tag`, as this deals with perishable data:

```
#app/views/elements/_search.html.erb
<%= form_tag "/search" do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :tf_Designation, nil, placeholder: "Designation" %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<% end %>

#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
def search
    @designation = params[:tf_Designation]
    unless @designation.blank?
       render '/index'
    end
end
```

Comment: I am getting error this (undefined local variable or method `designation') at this line "unless designation.blank?"

Comment: Apologies - it should have been `@designation`

Comment: I use this (@designation) but it shows in the text field ({:placeholder=>"Designation"})

Comment: Apologies - let me fix the syntax